# Material won't assign (assigned faces turn transparent).How do I fix it?

Tags: materials, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I tried following derrek's tutorial on lowpoly car. while assigning material i created a base material on the car and then i added another slot and made a glass material and when i go to edit mode and select windows and assign it turns transparent.
I just started blender and this thing is ticking me off.How do i fix it?
[image: the material is supposed to look like that of the cube but the window is transparent]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to uncheck 'Show backface' in material setting of window. Please check Image attached.[image]

Comment: I've tried it but it still doesnt fix the problem